# In Pokemon Sword/Shield Isle of Armor, Can You Get More Than 1 Galarica Cuff?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-isle-of-armor

I have collected the twigs to get a galarica cuff created for evolving the Galarian SlowBro. Can I only do this once or can more twigs be collected and more cuffs be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get more than one. The sparkling items on the ground have a chance to be Galarica twigs, and they respawn daily with no long-term limit. If you use something like the raid den exploit to force them to respawn you can farm them more or less continuously.